# Route53 to S3 static website redirect from https to http

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I have setup my domain in route53 with 2 different weighted A entries:

- "live": points to the live application (load balancer with ec2 instances)
- "maintenance": points to a static S3 website (html page telling site is down)

So I have scripts that make the live application go in maintenance mode and back to live (change weight of both A entries). This works perfectly, only now I access my application with HTTPS and this does not work with the S3 static site. Is it possible with route53 or somewhere else to make https calls redirect to the s3 static website using http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to change schemes from http to https using DNS... and redirecting from https to http is still going to require a successful connection to some kind of endpoint that also has a valid SSL cert for your domain.

However...  an interesting way to handle this would be to use Cloudfront, which would allow you to install your same SSL cert to front-end the static site in S3.  If your users' browsers can reasonably be expected to support SNI, this seems like a winner.

You'd want to configure the bucket as a "custom" origin with the S3 website endpoint as the origin... and you'd want `Cache-Control` headers on the bucket objects, configured so that browsers don't cache your "maintenance mode" pages.  (Actually, you'd want that,  whatever you do).

Comment: Hey, ok so I put cloudfront in front of the S3 static site. When I go to the cloudfront url it works (with https), but when I go to the domain name that has been configured with Route53 to this cloudfront (by alias) I get an "AccessDenied" error (403). Any idea what this could be? A policy I have to configure somewhere?

Comment: @NathanQ - In your Cloudfront configuration, did you add Cnames to your distribution? Also, don't forget to add your domain certificates to Cloudfront certificates. This is slightly different to how you do it for ELBs (Path has to be */cloudfront/path/*) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html#cnames-and-https-procedure  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html

Comment: It seems to work now. I added the CNAME some time ago, but maybe the changes I made weren't fully set yet when I tested. At the moment I'm just using some test certificates. But will change when I get the real certificate using the links you provided. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hmm, now when I change back to "live mode" (switch weights of Route53 A entries) it is still directing me to this cloudfront instead of to my loadbalancer. Is it because of the cname configuration? Or what could be causing this?

Comment: The CNAME you refer to... is in *CloudFront* configuration, not Route 53, correct?  If so, that's not the problem.  What response do you get on DNS queries?

Comment: My bad, it seems to be a browser caching problem and I probably configured it wrongly. Checking it out now.